# How to select top record of duplicates and create new table?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have following table:

```
=====================
RecNum ID     Date
=====================
12345  188832 2045-01-07
33445  188832 2035-10-01
66789  188849 2047-10-18
77889  340520 2047-04-28
99776  340520 2047-04-28
=====================
```

I need to generate a new table with only one ID corresponding to latest date.

As you can see ID 188832 has two dates:2045-01-07 and 2035-10-01.
I need only the latest one: 2045-01-07.

188849 has only one date and should be as is.
340520 has two records with same date - I need to choose only one.

RecNum is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ROW_NUMBER` should work here:

```
SELECT RecNum, ID, Date
FROM
(
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable t
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Note that in the case of `ID = 340520` the above query would arbitrarily choose one of the two records.  If you have some logic which determines how to handle such ties, the query can be modified.